# How to express $k$ in terms of $N$ given $1=\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{2}{k^{i+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a way to express $k$ in terms of $N$ given $$1=\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{2}{k^{i+1}}$$I tried using sum of a geometric sequence which yields

$$1=\frac{1}{k}+\frac{2}{k^2}\frac{1-\frac{1}{k^N}}{1-\frac{1}{k}}$$ but this doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Is there a way to do it or am I just stuck in the dead end?

Comment: Try to get the term $\frac{1}{k^N}$ alone in one side of the equality, after that evaluate both sides of the equality with the logarithm.

Comment: The question asks for $k(N)$

Answer (score 2):

$$1=\frac{1}{k}+\frac 2k\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{k^{i}}=\frac{-2 k^{-n}+k+1}{k(k-1)}$$

This means that you want to solve for $k$ the  equation
$$\frac{(k+1) k^n-2 }{ (k-1)\, k^{n+1}}=1$$ which makes a polynomial of degree $(n+2)$ in $k$.
$$k^{n+2}-2k^{n+1}-k^n+2=0$$ So, for $n>2$, no solutions and then numerical methods or approximations will be required.

Notice that, for $n=1$, the solutions are $k=-1$ and $k=2$ and that, for an infinite value of $n$, they are $k=1\pm \sqrt 2$. We shall try to only follow the positive root which is such that $2 \leq k_{(n)} < 1+ \sqrt 2$ (very narrow range). In any manner, in the real domain, there are only two roots (why ?).

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(k)=k^{n+2}-2k^{n+1}-k^n+2$$

By inspection, you could have checked that
$$f(2)=2-2^n <0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f(3)=2 \left(3^n+1\right)>0$$

At these simple bounds, the function values are very large, but (good surprise)
$$f(1+\sqrt 2)=2$$

To make the problem simple, performing one single iteration of Newton or Halley method with $k_0=(1+\sqrt 2)$.

With
$$f'(k)=k^{n-1} \big[ (n+2)k^2-2 (n+1)k-n\big]$$
$$f''(k)=k^{n-2} \big[(n+1) (n+2)k^2-2  n (n+1)k-n(n-1)\big]$$
we have
$$k^{\text{Newton}}_1=k_0-\frac {f(k_0)}{f'(k_0)}$$
$$k^{\text{Halley}}_1=k_0- \frac {2 f(k_0) f'(k_0)} {2 {[f'(k_0)]}^2 - f(k_0) f''(k_0)}$$

A few values for illustration

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & k^{\text{Newton}}_1 & k^{\text{Halley}}_1 & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 2.121320344 & 2.036348392 &  2.000000000 \\
 2 & 2.292893219 & 2.272583747 &  2.269530842 \\
 3 & 2.363961031 & 2.359578608 &  2.359304088 \\
 4 & 2.393398282 & 2.392489178 &  2.392463722 \\
 5 & 2.405591591 & 2.405407500 &  2.405405134 \\
 6 & 2.410642225 & 2.410605646 &  2.410605429 \\
 7 & 2.412734266 & 2.412727113 &  2.412727093 \\
 8 & 2.413600818 & 2.413599438 &  2.413599436 \\
 9 & 2.413959755 & 2.413959492 &  2.413959492 \\
 10 & 2.414108432 & 2.414108382 &  2.414108382
\end{array}
\right)$$

We could have better results using Householder method (or methods of higher order).

Comment: Maybe I understand your answer wrong, but could you not just substitute $k^n=z^n+1$ to get $$z^n(z^2-2z-1)=0$$ and so (apart from $z=0$) $z=1\pm \sqrt{2}$ i.e. $$k=\left(1+(1\pm\sqrt{2})^n\right)^{1/n} \,.$$

Comment: @Diger. Make $n=2$ and solve $k^3-k^2-2 k-2=0$ to get $k=2.26953$ while $k=\left(1+(1\pm\sqrt{2})^3\right)$ would give $k_+=5.82843$ and $k_-=1.17157$

Answer (score 1):

$$1=\frac{1}{k}+\frac{2}{k^2}\frac{1-\frac{1}{k^N}}{1-\frac{1}{k}}$$

$$\left(1-\frac1k\right)\frac{k^2}2\left(1-\frac1k\right)-1=-k^{-N}$$
$$-\left(1-\frac1k\right)^2\frac{k^2}2+1=k^{-N}$$
$$\log_{k}\left(1-\frac{(k-1)^2}{2}\right)=-N$$

Comment: OK . Now, what is $k(N)$ ?

Comment: I thought he asked for solving N in terms of k. Anyway sometimes studying the inverse function  can help to know about the original function